# Creating a View for just SharePoint Lists

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-designer, web-part, list-view

Is there a way to create a Web Part that would only show lists in SharePoint 365? I know how to add a web part that would show Document Libraries, etc., but I wonder if there a way to just show lists. The issue is that my site has a lot of Lists, Documents Libraries, etc, and when users go to Site Contents, it shows all of them, and I can't find a way to filter them by Type. Any hint would be appreciated.

Comment: yes, you can. Try it and let us know if/when you get stuck on something.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It’s true that we cannot filter site contents in SharePoint Online.

The direct way to display all lists would be to create a site page and then manually add all list web parts on the page. This process can be automated with PowerShell.

You can also use **Highlighted content web part**. Add the web part on a Site Page and apply custom query under “Query text (KQL)”.

This is the query text I use:

```
(contentclass:STS_List) -contentclass:STS_ListItem_  Path:https://{siteURL}/Lists/
```

[image]

References:

[Create Web Part in Modern SharePoint Online: PowerShell.](https://piyushksingh.com/2019/07/13/create-web-part-in-modern-sharepoint-online-powershell/)

[Use the Highlighted content web part.](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/use-the-highlighted-content-web-part-e34199b0-ff1a-47fb-8f4d-dbcaed329efd)

[SharePoint 2013 Keyword Query (KQL) Content Class Property Restrictions.](http://avalagopi767.blogspot.com/2016/02/sharepoint-2013-keyword-query-kql.html)

Comment: Brilliant. I haven't used the Highlighted Content Web Part option before, thanks for the suggestion. Just for curiosity, I wonder if would be better to just use REST instead (`_api/web/lists`).

Comment: @cubanGuy I’m not familiar with Search REST but of course you can give it a try.